# Execution failed for task ':ofbiz --load-data' while running OfBiz

Tags: gradle, windows-10-universal, ofbiz

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':ofbiz --load-data'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17.0.2\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Exception is:
  org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':ofbiz --load-data'.
  at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.lambda$executeIfValid$1(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:147)
  at org.gradle.internal.Try$Failure.ifSuccessfulOrElse(Try.java:282)

when i am trying build using gradle facing issue, any help appreciated.

`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not clear. In windows devices try `gradlew cleanAll loadAll ofbiz` command to load data and run ofbiz. If your issue is due to java version, try `Java 1.8` version. 
Visit below link of OFBiz development guide for more help 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/OFBIZ/OFBiz+Tutorial+-+A+Beginners+Development+Guide